# Failed Install Phanteon on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management

Help, please. What should I do?

```
Unpacking elementary-icon-theme (3.2.2+r1530+pkg27~daily~ubuntu0.3.1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/elementary-icon-theme_3.2.2+r1530+pkg27~daily~ubuntu0.3.1.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/icons/elementary/emotes/16/face-cool.svg', which is also in package elementary-icons 3.0-a~trusty~NoobsLab.com
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The packages `elementary-icon-theme` and `elementary-icons` both contain the file `/usr/share/icons/elementary/emotes/16/face-cool.svg` so you can install only one of them.

If you want to install `elementary-icon-theme` remove `elementary-icons` first.

Comment: Thank you, but when I try to remove elementary-icons  :   ega@ega-X455LD:~$ sudo apt-get remove elementary-icons
[sudo] password for ega: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 elementary-default-settings : Depends: elementary-icon-theme but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  elementary-icon-theme
Suggested packages:
  notify-osd-icons-elementary
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  elementary-icon-theme
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,664 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

Comment: (Reading database ... 345469 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../elementary-icon-theme_3.2.2+r1530+pkg27~daily~ubuntu0.3.1.1_all.deb ...

Comment: Unpacking elementary-icon-theme (3.2.2+r1530+pkg27~daily~ubuntu0.3.1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/elementary-icon-theme_3.2.2+r1530+pkg27~daily~ubuntu0.3.1.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/icons/elementary/emotes/16/face-cool.svg', which is also in package elementary-icons 3.0-a~trusty~NoobsLab.com
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/elementary-icon-theme_3.2.2+r1530+pkg27~daily~ubuntu0.3.1.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)